# Is this possible to create many form designs and swap between them?

Tags: c#, forms

I've just started building up a simple game in Visual Studio using c# (It is my first low difficulty game). As I open it , it shows me a background image and 2 buttons, "Play" and "Instructions."and I want the form to get changed as I click the play button and open a new menu interface , like : " Game Difficulty / Character Appearence "(those 2 are buttons) , with a new background image. When I click one of them, another menu, etc.
    Can I create multiple designs( Form1.cs[Design1/2/3]) for my from and swap between them ? If not, then how can I do something similar ?

Comment: Hello Ncs. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share with us what you have tried thus far? What worked? What didn't? Help us, help you. Have you consider looking up MDI and/or Modal forms? Please, tell us what paths you have researched so we can help you on your search.

Comment: I've tried to create new forms and swap between them, which is not what I wished for. I want only the screen to get changed and the app to run on a single form, without any other forms popping up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to make each menu a "User Control" that is the size of the main form, and then you can add a user control for whichever menu you want to show up as you go along.

For example, in the solution explorer I would create a folder and name it "Menus". Then I would create a new "User Control" in there. Copy the Width and Height of the form it will be placed on and apply that to the new control. Then you can add in all the buttons and images you like. Once you're finished, in your main form, you can add the "main-menu" control you made in the designer. For any submenus you want, create user controls for them too. Then, if you want a submenu to show up, capture a click event for the button you want and programmatically add it to the parent form using FindForm().

Pretend that DifficultyScreenControl is the screen that shows up after I click a play button located in my main-menu user control.

*Inside of a menu user control*

```
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DifficultyScreenControl DiffScr = new DifficultyScreen();
    this.FindForm().Controls.Add(DiffScr);
}
```

Also it is a good idea to either Dispose() or remove these screens one they can't be revisited again as it can free up resources being taken up by them.

Feel free to ask me questions or comment on things to change!

Comment: Thank you, so far this helps me get the best outcome from my code ! Is there any way I can stop the buttons that i was using before the DiffScr come up ? I mean the PLAY and INSTRUCTION buttons, I want them to be disabled until I come back on my Main Menu. I tried to set each one of them invisible, can I disable them , so they dont run during my other menus ?